# Как сортировать сообщения в диалоги на PHP?

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть сообщения из БД, как сделать что-то типо диалогов. Чтобы показывалось только последнее сообщение (проверка по логину).

Вот массив:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [login] => admin
        [text] => как длеа
        [date] => 1562313697
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [login] => stone
        [text] => тест
        [date] => 1562313674
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [login] => admin
        [text] => Привет
        [date] => 1562313477
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [login] => user
        [text] => хай
        [date] => 1562114203
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [login] => moderator
        [text] => 12345
        [date] => 1562113713
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [login] => user
        [text] => zzz
        [date] => 1562112784
    )
```

Должно на выходе быть:

```
      [0] => Array
    (
        [login] => admin
        [text] => как длеа
        [date] => 1562313697
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [login] => stone
        [text] => тест
        [date] => 1562313674
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [login] => user
        [text] => хай
        [date] => 1562114203
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [login] => moderator
        [text] => 12345
        [date] => 1562113713
    )
```

Comment: Как вариант сортировать на уровне выгрузки из БД? Если хотите сортировать в PHP, попробуйте https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: @ДмитрийГорный `usort` тут нужен для пхп. но на стороне пхп такое не делают.

Comment: @ДмитрийГорный не подскажите как примерно будет на SQL выглядеть запрос для сортировки? Вот таблица: https://ibb.co/j578SKz

Comment: @wherermymind `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 1 ORDER BY date DESC` (DESC по убыванию, ASC по возрастанию)

Comment: @ДмитрийГорный мне нужно в виде диалогов, чтобы не было повторов

Comment: Группировать по sender_id или reveiver_id - выбирать вам, т.к. я не знаю точной архитектуры.

Comment: @ДмитрийГорный date_last это что? после FROM два раза имя таблицы?

Comment: Удалил прошлый коммент, он не всегда верно бы работал, без вложенного запроса не сделать: `SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY date DESC
) tmp
GROUP BY sender_id`

Comment: Поменяйте `your_table` на название вашей таблицы и попробуйте выполнить запрос.

Comment: @ДмитрийГорный Пишет ошибку: #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'tmp.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Тут несколько вариантов, сначала попробуйте выбирать только нужные столбцы, без `*`, т.е. к примеру `SELECT id,text,sender_id FROM ( SELECT date,sender_id,id FROM your_table ORDER BY date DESC ) tmp GROUP BY sender_id` если не поможет, или переписывать запрос или как тут советуют сделать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc

Comment: @ДмитрийГорный а что "tmp" в данном запросе? Я ноль в SQL.

Comment: Это алиас, просто обозвали выборку как `tmp`

Comment: Если вы тестите на локальном сервере - то сделайте запрос `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));` и попробуйте сделать выборку